# How to move to another activity after POST data with retrofit android?

Tags: android, android-intent, retrofit, retrofit2

I wanna ask something. So I have an activity to do registration for a new user. The flow for creating an account is that when a user fills the form and sends it to the server, then the server will check the data received whether it's already in the database or not. After that, if the data is new then the user confirmed as successfully registered and the apps will redirect the user to login activity. In this case, the data has been successfully inserted to the database but the logcat show me a line like this:

```
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned
```

along with this:

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9ed852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9ed831d0)
E/ERROR :: timeout
```

also, it didn't open the login activity even the data is successfully inserted.
Here is my ApiClient.java:

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String url){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                            .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .build())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Is there something that I missed? Cause when I try it just the basic ones, I mean like passing it through intent and no post action, it works. But when I try it along with POST action, the error thing comes out

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured out the solution. So basically in the server-side hasn't been registered to SMTP so it makes the connection request via client android become so slow. Therefore, I decided to try it first via the local server and it makes the client working perfectly fine. Nothing's wrong with the client code. Thank You for those who have read my issue. :D